# How does react-table v7.7.9 work in typescript with global filtering

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-table, react-table-v7

I have a `react-table` that is working nicely in typescript.

```
  const { getTableProps, getTableBodyProps, headerGroups, rows, prepareRow } = useTable(
    { columns, data }
  );
```

I would like to add global filtering.  If I simply add the plugin hook, it compiles:

```
  const { getTableProps, getTableBodyProps, headerGroups, rows, prepareRow } = useTable(
    { columns, data },
    useGlobalFilter
  );
```

But if I try to add the `setGlobalFilter` option, I get a compiler error:

```
  const { getTableProps, getTableBodyProps, headerGroups, rows, prepareRow, setGlobalFilter } = useTable(
    { columns, data },
    useGlobalFilter
  );
```

```
ERROR in src/components/SubmissionTable.tsx:144:77
TS2339: Property 'setGlobalFilter' does not exist on type 'TableInstance<TableModel>'.
```

I have `"@types/react-table": "^7.7.9"` in my dev-dependencies and can confirm that it can find those types.  It's not clear to me why it won't allow me to use setGlobalFilter after I pass in the useGlobalFilter plugin/hook.

Answer (score 9):

> It's not clear to me why it won't allow me to use setGlobalFilter
> after I pass in the useGlobalFilter plugin/hook.

Authors of react-table lib do not providing @types/react-table support, it is 3rd party project made by someone else.

You can use this hack: [github: DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/react-table)
It makes all plugin extensions available, but less stricter.

Edit:
Working [sandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/all-columns-global-filter-buof9) made by this guy [Richard Beattie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3949864/richard-beattie)

Comment: This is great.  